# Plot holes in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban?

Tags: harry-potter

In “Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban”, I am confused about the whole ending. Why wouldn’t Professors Snape and Lupin (the werewolf) tell the Ministry the whole story, since they were both there? It makes sense that they don’t believe three kids, but if both Professors tell them, then it still could have set Sirius Black free without him having to run away. Also, if Dumbledore knew they time-traveled, then he also could have said something.

Second question: if after time-traveling, Black “escaped” and was still wanted, then why at the end of the movie was castle no longer guarded? It seems like there would have been EXTRA protection if he was thought to flee for a second time.

Comment: remember: being a werewolf, Lupin is basically not trusted by anyone except Dumbledore His testimony would be fairly worthless

Comment: Snape was unconscious when Scabbers was revealed to be Pettigrew. Without witnessing that, Snape would still believe Sirius was guilty.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this being voted down?   Are plot holes discouraged questions?

Comment: My guess for the downvote would be that those plot hole exists only in the movie (if they exists are all), everything is clearly explained in the book

Comment: There are just too many for one question. “Why wouldn’t Snape tell Ministry?” Or “Why we’re there no guards?” Needs to pick a hole. Also the title isn’t even a question.

Answer (score 4):

> Why wouldn’t Professors Snape and Lupin (the werewolf) tell the Ministry the whole story, since they were both there?

Professor Snape was there, but he was unconscious for most of the event, so he didn't *know* the whole story. As for Lupin, he's just been outed as a werewolf, a creature regularly discriminated against due to its violent behaviour when the full moon rises. Nobody would have believed him any more than they would have believed Harry.

> Also, if Dumbledore knew they time-traveled, then he also could have said something.

They weren't supposed to have done that, though. Use of time travel is *very* strictly regulated: the main trio would have gotten in trouble for it, and Dumbledore would have gotten in trouble for allowing it. Aside from the time travel, I'm not sure what evidence Dumbledore had that Sirius was innocent, and without any evidence, Fudge (who resents Dumbledore) would have been all too happy to disregard even *his* testimony.

> If after time-traveling, Black “escaped” and was still wanted, then why at the end of the movie was castle no longer guarded?

Dumbledore didn't want the Dementors at Hogwarts in the first place. The fact that they didn't even do their job properly, by seemingly allowing Black to escape, would have been exactly the excuse he needed to get rid of them. Not to mention the fact that they attacked and nearly killed his star student on no less than *three* occasions.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than enough plot holes.

But in this case, Snape wants Black dead, so he doesn't tell, Lupin is a werewolf, nobody would listen to him.

This is between the Minister and Snape:

> “Shocking business … shocking … miracle none of them died … never heard the like … by thunder, it was lucky you were there, Snape. …”
>
> “Thank you, Minister.”
>
> “Order of Merlin, Second Class, I’d say. First Class, if I can wangle it!”
>
> “Thank you very much indeed, Minister.”
>
> “Nasty cut you’ve got there. … Black’s work, I suppose?”
>
> “As a matter of fact, it was Potter, Weasley, and Granger, Minis­ter. …”
>
> “No!”
>
> “Black had bewitched them, I saw it immediately. A Confundus Charm, to judge by their behavior. They seemed to think there was a possibility he was innocent.

The real question is, why didn't Dumbledore do anything, as he is the Chief Warlock?
The in-universe explanation is that he wanted Harry back at the Dursleys.

Maybe the Dementors were removed because they had not been effective.

Comment: "Maybe the Dementors were removed because they had not been effective." Not to mention that a) they attacked and nearly killed Harry on multiple occasions, and b) IIRC, Dumbledore didn't want them there in the first place. He'd be all too glad to see the back of them.

Comment: @F1Krazy True, but both were already true when the Dementors attacked the Quiddich game. Out of universe, they are just no longer needed for the plot.

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, you're right.   We, theoretically, live in a world where new evidence means a case against someone can be re-opened or reviewed.   The wizarding world's trial process comes across as a bit barbaric and rush to judgement.   The memory that Harry saw of the trial of Igor Karkaroff seemed almost mob rules court and all Karkaroff had to do was name a new name and he gets off?   Flawed system for sure.  I mean, what if the person you name is a smaller risk than you, how does that serve public safety?

As for the evidence, Lupin saw Pettigrew, Lupin, who was for years, convinced that Sirius had killed his friends, only now changes his mind?    Pettigrew was the person that Sirius black was charged with killing and if people start seeing him alive that should call into question whether the charges were accurate.

The kids all saw Pettigrew.   Multiple people could have testified to Scabbers "unusually long life".  They could have presented the map as reasons why they thought Pettigrew was alive in the first place and I would add to that, Dumbledor believing the story would add further credence to Sirius being innocent.   All that, together should be more than enough raise reasonable doubt in any fair court system, but if they don't have a fair court system, if kids and wearwolf testimony doesn't matter, then it's not a plot hole.

I think it's more accurate to say that JK did a poor job of developing a justice system in her wizarding world more than it was actually a plot hole.   The abrupt death sentence in the middle of magnificent beasts is another example of that kind of rush to judgement and death sentence, that JK just seems to insert in her books as a plot device.  Even if it was (spoiler), bad guy in polijuice/disguise, that kind of abrupt sentencing of two people to immediate death seemed a bit much.

[Article on same](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/lets-talk-about-that-messed-up-death-penalty-in-fantastic-beasts-for-just-a-minute_n_582f07cde4b058ce7aaa9c28)

Also, the "[death cell](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Cell)", and I don't object to the death cell as a plot device. It's a kind of cool idea which looks like an electric chair and pays homage to the 17th century cucking stool.   I object only to JK's tendency to write rushed judgement rather than a more civilized wizard justice system.   Even Harry's impromptu hearing before the ministry after defending himself from a dementor near his house, came across as a bit of a kangaroo court almost straight out of the French revolution.